# How do I get a user's browser history using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zendesk

I want to get a user's browser history using javascript. How can I do that? I want to get that information and store it in a textfield. I want to integrate this into zendesk so that I know where the user came from when they clicked on support to get to my zendesk page.

Comment: You can't. reading the JS history object is restricted to prevent privacy violations. it is none of your site's business to see what a user's browsing history is, even if you (might) have a legitimate need for that data. If YOU can access the data, then ANY site could also access the same data.

Comment: Agree with Marc B.  You can leverage window.opener and document.referrer only (if they exist).

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, you can not access history. However, if you are looking to see where do they come from on your product page, you can:

1. Use the Pathfinder app, which now can be integrated with the Web Widget to show a timeline of the pages that the user visited on your website and Help Center. The info of the pathfinder app is only accessible through the agent interface, though: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224815428-Announcing-Pathfinder-app-enhancements
2. Add some identification on the query string when you link them to your Help Center from your product page. EG. "https://something.zendesk.com/hc/en-us?referrer_page=%27purchase_page%27"

If you want to see where did they come from outside of your product page it's a different story and there's many other places where you can find discussions about it.

Answer (score -2):

You can now actually, its really easy.

Create a google play chrome app that activates on all websites which just grabs the sites url and stores it in a json object and have that json object written to local or session storage and when the user accesses your site grab the information from local or session storage.